# Updating SharePoint Managed Metadata fields using values from CSV file

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, managed-metadata

## I have been tasked to update metadata fields in a document library by reading inputs from a CSV file. Based on my little understanding of powershell, I have written the code below but it doesn't work. I hope someone can help me. Sorry if this is not an appropriate forum for this.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;

$siteobj = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://myServer:9600/sites/custdocstore1")
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://myServer:9600/sites/custdocstore1"

$session = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession($siteobj)

$CRMCols = Import-Csv "G:\Backup files\MetadataUpdateFromCRMToSharePointFew.csv";

#Getting the term (new value) to which we want to update the column 
$termstore = $session.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"];  
$group = $termstore.Groups["MyCompany Customer Document Management"]; 
$termset = $group.TermSets["Document Category"];

#List/Library we want to update 
$list=$web.Lists["Documents"]; 
$taxfield = $list.Fields["Doc Category"] -as [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField];

#Assign CSV column values to variables 
foreach($CRMCol in $CRMCols) 
{ 
$CRMOrg = $CRMCol.Organisation;

$CRMDC = $CRMCol.Doc_Category;

$spFile = $web.GetFile($CRMOrg);

$termValue = $CRMDC;

$term = $termset.Terms[$termValue];

$itemValue = $spFile.items;

#SetFieldValue function is used to update taxonomy field 
$taxField.SetFieldValue($itemValue,$term);

$itemValue.SystemUpdate();

}

write-host -ForegroundColor Green "Disposing the web Object.."; 

$web.Dispose();
```

Comment: How do you know which items in the library to update or will all items get the same term? $itemValue really should not be $list.items as the latter is a collection. You will need to iterate through it.

Comment: Thank you, Bunzab. Actually, I had a GetFile function that called up the document but I wasn't very sure whether it was necessary.  I will edit the code for you to see.

Comment: Hi Bunzab, I have added the text in bold but I'm afraid it doesn't work either. Hope you can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
$CRMOrg = $CRMCol.Organisation
$termValue = $CRMCol.Doc_Category
#Does this return a valid SPFile Object: 
$spFile = $web.GetFile($CRMOrg)
$term = $termset.Terms[$termValue]
$taxField.SetFieldValue($spFile.Item, $term)
$spFile.SystemUpdate()
```

Use PowerShell ISE to test this and add breakpoints (F9) at various stages to validate the process.

Comment: Hi Bunzab, Thank you very much for your help. I stepped through but had the error below on the SystemUpdate line.  All the lines are OK
===========================================

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At G:\Backup files\Emml-Scritps&SiteColls\UpdatingManagedMetadatafromCSV_DRAFT.ps1:34 char:1
+ $itemValue.SystemUpdate()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: Sorry the item needs updated. Modified to $spFile.SystemUpdate().

Comment: Thank you Bunzab.  This is the new error
============================

Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile] doesn't contain a method named 'SystemUpdate'.
At G:\Backup files\Emml-Scritps&SiteColls\UpdatingManagedMetadatafromCSV_DRAFT.ps1:34 char:1
+ $spFile.SystemUpdate()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: $spFile.item.SystemUpdate() works